# Generic solution to get default values of all properties in a range of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, reflection

I want to get back the default values of all properties in a range of objects. The logic used is that if all of the property values in the range are the same, then use that for the default value, otherwise leave it null/type default.

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but I'm open to all suggestions. I have created a working solution that is fairly generic, but I want it to be more so if possible. The current problem is that I have to have the if/elseif chain of the same code with a single difference of explicitly defining the type. I couldn't figure out how to get back the GetValue of the PropertyInfo and have the type properly pass into the generic functions. Once I got the object back, it would always pass down into the Generic as 'object' instead of 'int','decimal', etc. I also ran into the boxing/unboxing issue with nullables. I tried setting up the GetPropertyValue function with a generic return, but that requires you to pass in the type, which I'm not doing since I get it inside the function.

All of this code is just a working example.  My classes have hundreds of properties and with 30 different classes, thats around 3000 properties I don't want to explicitly write out.

```
public class MainFunction
{
    public MainFunction()
    {
        ParentClass defaultClass = new ParentClass();

        List<ParentClass> results = MyDatabaseCallThatGetsBackListOfClass();

        defaultClass = Generic.GetDefaultProperty(defaultClass, results);
    }

    private List<ParentClass> MyDatabaseCallThatGetsBackListOfClass()
    {
        List<ParentClass> populateResults = new List<ParentClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            populateResults.Add(new ParentClass()
            {
                Class1 = new SubClass1()
                {
                    Property1 = "Testing",
                    Property2 = DateTime.Now.Date,                        
                    Property3 = true,
                    Property4 = (decimal?)1.14,
                    Property5 = (i == 1 ? 5 : 25), // different, so should return null
                    Class1 = new SubSubClass1()
                    {
                        Property1 = "Test"
                    },
                    Class2 = new SubSubClass2()
                },
                Class2 = new SubClass2()
                {
                    Property1 = null,
                    Property2 = 10,
                    Property3 = (i == 1 ? 15 : 30), // different, so should return null
                    Property4 = 20
                }
            });
        }
        return populateResults;
    }
}

public class ParentClass
{
    public ParentClass()
    {
        this.Class1 = new SubClass1();
        this.Class2 = new SubClass2();
    }

    public SubClass1 Class1 { get; set; }
    public SubClass2 Class2 { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass1
{
    public SubClass1()
    {
        this.Class1 = new SubSubClass1();
        this.Class2 = new SubSubClass2();
    }

    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Property2 { get; set; } 
    public bool? Property3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Property4 { get; set; } 
    public int? Property5 { get; set; }

    public bool Property6 { get; set; }
    public decimal Property7 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Property8 { get; set; }
    public int Property9 { get; set; }

    public SubSubClass1 Class1 { get; set; }
    public SubSubClass2 Class2 { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass2
{
    public int? Property1 { get; set; }
    public int? Property2 { get; set; }
    public int Property3 { get; set; }
    public int Property4 { get; set; }
}

public class SubSubClass1
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class SubSubClass2
{
    public decimal? Property1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Property2 { get; set; }
}

public static class Generic
{
    public static T GetDefaultProperty<T>(T defaultItem, List<T> itemList)
        where T : class
    {
        Type defaultType = defaultItem.GetType();
        var props = defaultType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.CanRead);
        foreach (var p in props)
        {
            if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && p.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            {
                dynamic classProperty = GetPropertyValue(defaultItem, p.Name);
                var classList = GetClassSubList(itemList, classProperty, p.Name);
                p.SetValue(defaultItem, GetDefaultProperty(classProperty, classList), null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (p.PropertyType == typeof(int?))
                {
                    List<int?> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<int?>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
                else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(bool?))
                {
                    List<bool?> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<bool?>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
                else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal?))
                {
                    List<decimal?> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<decimal?>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
                else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                {
                    List<DateTime?> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<DateTime?>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
                else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {
                    List<string> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<string>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
                else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                {
                    List<int> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<int>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
                else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    List<bool> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<bool>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
                else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
                {
                    List<decimal> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<decimal>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
                else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    List<DateTime> subList = GetPropertySubList(itemList, TypeDefault<DateTime>(), p.Name);
                    if (subList.Distinct().ToList().Count == 1)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return defaultItem;
    }

    private static object GetPropertyValue<T>(T item, string propertyName)
    {
        if (item == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            return null;
        }
        PropertyInfo pi = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (pi == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (!pi.CanRead)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return pi.GetValue(item, null);
    }

    private static List<TReturn> GetClassSubList<T, TReturn>(List<T> list, TReturn returnType, string propertyName)
        where T : class
        where TReturn : class
    {
        return list.Select(GetClassSelection<T, TReturn>(propertyName)).ToList();
    }

    private static Func<T, TReturn> GetClassSelection<T, TReturn>(string fieldName)
        where T : class
        where TReturn : class
    {
        ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        var body = Expression.Property(p, fieldName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TReturn>>(body, new ParameterExpression[] { p }).Compile();
    }

    private static List<TReturn> GetPropertySubList<T, TReturn>(List<T> list, TReturn returnType, string propertyName)
        where T : class
    {
        return list.Select(GetPropertySelection<T, TReturn>(propertyName)).ToList();
    }

    private static Func<T, TReturn> GetPropertySelection<T, TReturn>(string fieldName)
        where T : class
    {
        ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        var body = Expression.Property(p, fieldName);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TReturn>>(body, new ParameterExpression[] { p }).Compile();
    }

    private static T TypeDefault<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: 100's of properties and 30 classes?  Effectively redesigning the default value system in C# is terribly confusing as it goes against the standards of the language itself.  Solve your problem by creating an architecture for this code that makes sense.  Studying cohesion is a good place to begin.

Comment: How does that not make sense? Even if it was 2 classes with 30 properties, that would still take alot of code to do what I need to do. At least here I only have to explicitly cast each type instead of a giant if chain of `if(results.Select(r => r.Class1.Property1).Distinct().ToList().Count == 1){ default.Class1.Property1 = results.First().Class1.Property1;}`

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I think having business logic for defaults is legitimate. But I agree with you that 100+ properties per class is smelly - to say the least. \anderezekial can you give some more background as to why you're doing this? We may be able to improve this at a higher level.

Comment: @GertArnold I'd love to have an example where reflecting through N number of types to effectively override the default value system is a good solution.  It would have to be an oustanding reason to justify this level of cyclomatic complexity IMO.

Comment: @GertArnold Sure. I have a bunch of vehicle classes that have very specific properties. So as an example, a Bumper class that has BumperFrontHeight, BumperRearHeight, BumperFrontHeightFromGround, BumperRearHeightFromGround, etc. All of these values are recorded and used. So while I have base classes and inherit to try to keep common properties in a single classes, there is still a ton of properties.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I think you may be confused by what I mean by 'default values'. I mean the values of the properties themselves.  So if all the int Property1 are equal to 2 in all of the SubClass2 objects, then assign 2 to the default object SubClass2.NumberofDoors, otherwise it would be 0.

Comment: Er, meant SubClass2.Property1 in my previous post.

Comment: Your "subclasses" are not subclasses... if they were you would just do it in the parent class constructor.

Comment: @Yaur In my example, this is true. They are not real subclasses in that they do not inherit from a base class. Bad naming on my part for my example I guess. But what do you mean by "you would just do it in the parent class constructor"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the huge IF statement block with this:

```
var result = itemList.Select(x => p.GetValue(x, null)).Distinct();
if (result.Count() == 1)
{
    p.SetValue(defaultItem, result.First(), null);
}
```

If you use Distinct(), references/value types are compared using object.Equals that first tests reference equality, and later actual values. This method has only one draw-back: boxing/unboxing. Use that code for reference types.

Note: there's already a lot of boxing happening in you code.
Reflection is based on a "object", so it's pretty hard not to have boxing issues.

For example:

```
Type defaultType = defaultItem.GetType(); // boxing on value types.
p.SetValue(defaultItem, subList.FirstOrDefault(), null); // boxing
```

Boxing is minor cost with reflection. You can run benchmarks to check.

As for your actual problem; you have list of objects and you want to compare them all, recursively. If there is no difference between two objects, you want to set the property in defaultItem to a property value that all objects share.

Ignoring the reason for whatever reason you're doing this(since I don't care; rather the solution to this problem is interesting), let's continue :P

Your best bet is to generate strongly-typed comparer on startup using reflection. Generate the code using StringBuilder and later use CSharpCodeProvider() to compile from StringBuilder and return strongly-typed delegate that has no reflection overhead. This is the fastest one I can think of, right now. The only hit it will take is the first interrogation of reflection metadata on startup. It's only per T.

On production code, you can cache that strongly typed comparer onto DLL, so the hit will be only one-time event.

```
private static class StrongClassComparer<T>
{
    public static Func<T, string> GenerateMethod()
    {
        var code = new StringBuilder();

        // generate your STRONGLY-TYPED code here.
        // into code variable.
        code.Append("public class YourClassInCode { "+
             " public static string YourClassStaticMethod("+ typeof(T).Name+ " test)" + 
               " { return string.Empty; } }");

        var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof (T).Assembly.Location);
        parameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize + ";

        var results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code.ToString());
        var @class = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("YourClassInCode");
        var method = @class.GetMethod("YourClassStaticMethod");

        return (Func<T, string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (Func<T, string>), method);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I'll be looking into the strongly-typed comparer, but any useful links/resources on the topic wouldn't go amiss!

Comment: added something to get you going. ps generating just means reflection + string appending.